# Disallowing concurrent logins for same user at once

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I am working on a project , first i did user signup and login based on jwt authentication * note i am using reactjs * i want to disallow users from logging in several time from different tabs or browsers , what shall i do ? how to implement such service and where? i will provide the whol code that may be helpful

This is my main express file :

```
//the main framework , express
var express = require('express');
//path , used for joining pathes
var path = require('path');
//cross origin resource sharing 
var cors= require('cors')
//body parser used to take data from forms , to be used later on
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
//for security reasons , http security(not https)
var helmet= require('helmet')
//for parsing tokens and session cookies
var cookieParser= require('cookie-parser')
//assigning express functionaities as a global variable
const app = express()
//assigning cors functionaities as a global variable
app.use(cors())



//headers that will be sent to the browser
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', ['PATCH', 'POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT']);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers' , '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers' ,'content-type')
  next();
});

//body parser for form data
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser())
// secure apps by setting various HTTP headers
app.use(helmet())
// enable CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing
 app.options('*', cors()); 


//fetching index from react
app.use(express.static('./build/'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html')))  ;
});

//giving the functionalities of users.js to a variable users to be used later on
var Users = require('./routes/Users')
//using the functions assigned for users
app.use('/users', Users)

//exporting the app file 
 module.exports = app
```

this is the routes file which contains my controller:

```
const express = require('express')
//setting a users variable to be used as a router instead of app post , get ..
const users = express.Router()
//cross oigin resource sharing 
const cors = require('cors')
//jwt for user login authentication
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
//bcrypt for password encryption and decryption
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
//using te user model
const User = require('../model/user')
//setting users as cros origin functionalities
users.use(cors())
//privat key or jwt encryption and decryption
process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'q1w2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9p0o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1'

//main signup function , exported
users.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  //setting a new user object to be manipulated and inserted to db 
  //data taken from react client side 
  const today = new Date()
  const userData = {
    username : req.body.username,
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    created: today
  }

  //a function from sequelize , a wrapper for later on functions
  //searches if the username is found or not 
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      //searching in the whhole db for this user name 
     username: req.body.username
    }
  })
    // encrypting the password using bcrypt encryption function
    //bcrypt uses a hash function to encrypt the user given password
    //will not reach this part if user is duplicated
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        //hashing the password , 10 is a number for permutations 2pwr10 = a certain string built in
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          userData.password = hash
          //creating a user with the given data
          User.create(userData)
          //send the username to the response tab in console
            .then(user => {
              res.json({ status: user.username + '    '+ 'Registered!' })
            })
            //any error will be consoled here
            .catch(err => {
              res.send('error: ' + err)
            })
        })
      } else {
        //will reach if username is found ,  User.findOne 
        res.json({ error: 'User already exists' })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

//main login functionality
users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  ///searches for username in db at first
  User.findOne({
    where: {
     username: req.body.username
    }
  })
  //if the user is found , it compared the password with the given password
  //it compared it the encrypted pass in the db
  //and decrypts it to compare
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        //if user name is found the deryption starts here
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          //each user is given a certain jwt token for authentication
          //jwt.sign , Synchronously sign the given payload into a JSON Web Token string payload
          //secret key provided above
          //token is assigned using the front end whuck sends it with the request
          let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: 1440
          })
          //send token to local storage of the browser that checks it 
          res.send(token)
        }
      } else {
        //reaches here if user isnt found
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'User does not exist' })
      }
    })
    //catches any error from the above blocks
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err })
    })
})

users.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  //Synchronously verify given token using a secret or a public key to get a decoded token token -
  // JWT string to verify secretOrPublicKey - Either the secret for HMAC algorithms, 
  //or the PEM encoded public key for RSA and ECDSA.
  // [options] - Options for the verification returns - The decoded token.
  var decoded = jwt.verify(req.headers['authorization'], process.env.SECRET_KEY)


  //searches for user
  User.findOne({
    //decode user id and jwt 
    where: {
      id: decoded.id

    }

  })
  //if true, user is sent as a json object to browser
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user)
        res.json(user)
      } else {
        //if false , send this response
        res.send('User does not exist')
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

module.exports = users
```

react front end end-points:

```
 import axios from 'axios'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
//the signup endpoint sent from front end and interpreted by the browser
//route is an api called users , exported from server side
//posting user data as in server
//sending a response if true
export const signup = newUser => {
  return axios
    .post('users/signup', {
      username : newUser.username,
      first_name: newUser.first_name,
      last_name: newUser.last_name,
      email: newUser.email,
      password: newUser.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Registered')
    })
}

//login end point
//using username and password , using the decoded id 
export const login = async user => {
  try {
    const response = await axios
      .post('users/login', {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password
      });
    localStorage.setItem('usertoken', response.data);
    return response.data;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Login react page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {  withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import { login } from './api-user'


class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {}
    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

//   parseJwt(token) {
//     if (!token) { return; }
//     const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
//     const base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
//     return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
// }

onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const user = {
    username:this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password
  }

  login(user).then(res => {
    if (res) {
      this.props.history.push(`/profile`)
    }
  })
  localStorage.setItem('username',
  JSON.stringify(this.state.username))
}


  render() {
  return (



      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="text">Username</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="username"
                  placeholder="Enter username"
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
              >
                Sign in
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


  )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

signup react page

```
mport React, { Component } from 'react'
import { signup } from './api-user'

class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      username:'',
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {}
    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const newUser = {
      username: this.state.username,
      first_name: this.state.first_name,
      last_name: this.state.last_name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    signup(newUser).then(res => {
      this.props.history.push(`/login`)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="username">User Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="username"
                  placeholder="Enter your username"
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="first_name">First name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="first_name"
                  placeholder="Enter your first name"
                  value={this.state.first_name}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="last_name">Last name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="last_name"
                  placeholder="Enter your lastname name"
                  value={this.state.last_name}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
              >
                Register!
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default SignUp
```

App.js main routing file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'


import Landing from './components/user/Landing'
import Login from './components/user/Login'
import SignUp from './components/user/Signup'
import Profile from './components/user/Profile'


class App extends Component {




  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
        <Route exact path="/landing" component={Landing} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <div className="container">
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />

            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
  }


export default App
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I highly recommend taking a look at this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask –the code here is far too long for a ["Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) As such your question will most likely be ignored by the majority of the community. To get better quality answers, reduce the scope of what you are asking people to look at.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure about how much of a scope you expect as an answer for this question but assuming you need the React solution, this is the basic approach you can take in your situation.

You can check for the availability of **usertoken** you store in localStorage at the login (since it is your root route) and do what is necessary (Redirect to the profile page maybe);

As an example,

```
// Use this lifecycle hook to check for the token before doing anything else
componentDidMount() {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
   if (token) this.props.history.push(`/profile`);
}
```

Although this will not work for multiple browsers. For that, you will have to manage a session from the server side.

Comment: alternatively we can allow the login in the current window and logout/redirect on the other open tabs. (using BroadcastChannel API or BroadcastChannel library or storage events)

Comment: Never save the token in the local storage

Answer (score 1):

If you want user can login with single device at time then you have manage the jwt token in database.
Suppose first time a user login with a device A then save token in database and send to token in api for front use.Now same user login with device B then user will login successful but put old token which is from device A in blacklist in jwt and database too. When device A user will hit any api then you have to check this user token is expired or in blacklist then you can clear localstorage redirect to login page.
Instead of multiple devices, this scenario will work for multiple browsers and multiple window of browsers.

Comment: how can i do such operation ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use only one pair "access_token"/"refresh_token" for each user. If the user will log in on another tab (browser... client...), your server side should disable exist tokens (access+refresh) for that user.

Comment: bro i am understanding the concept but not knowing how to implement

Comment: can you help me code ? i have a deadline and i have passed it

Comment: @GhadikhaledMdallal I'm too busy right now, one important thing: JWT isn't supported the instantaneous logout (both tokens have own lifetimes), to fix that you have to create a BLACK LIST with invalid tokens (based on a memory storage, for instance - Reddis).